# Birational morphisms from DM stacks to their coarse moduli spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be an integral scheme over a field. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$ faithfully. Assume the quotient stack $[X/G]$ is separated (e.g., when $G$ acts on $X$ properly). Then $[X/G]$ is a separated Deligne-Mumford (DM) stack and there is a coarse moduli space
$$\pi:[X/G] \to X/G.$$
Is $\pi$ always a birational morphism of DM stacks?

Comment: What if $X$ has multiple components, with different elements of $G$ acting trivially on each?

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for the comment. I edited the question to avoid that case.

Comment: I think we're still in trouble if we just glue the components together. (Say two $\mathbb P^1$s joined at a point, and the group generated by two involutions of the separate $\mathbb P^1$s that each fix the other one, and thus that point.) Maybe you want to assume $X$ is irreducible?

Comment: @WillSawin That is still not enough.  Consider the action of $\mu_\ell$ on $\text{Spec}\ k[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^{\ell} \rangle$ by $\zeta\bullet \epsilon = \zeta\epsilon$.  This is a "faithful" action, but the map from the stack to the coarse moduli space is not birational.  The correct hypothesis is that for every generic point of $X$, the induced action of $G$ on the residue field of the point is faithful.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the example. Now the scheme $X$ is assumed to be integral, i.e., irreducible and reduced.

Comment: Yes, I think. For each nontrivial element $g\in G$, the fixed points form a closed set, which must not contain the whole space as then $g$ would act trivially. The complementary open set thus contains the generic point.

The intersection of these open sets over all nontrivial $g\in G$ forms an open set $U$ which is $G$-invariant. Restricted to $U$, the action of $G$ is free. Thus, the image of $U$ in the stack $X/G$ is the quotient $U/G$, which is an algebraic space, and so the image of $U/G$ in the coarse moduli space of $X/G$ is again isomorphic to $U/G$.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for the argument. It's neat! So we need the reducedness of $X$ to ensure each open set $X \setminus X^g$ is non-empty, and the irreducibility of $X$ to ensure the intersection $U$ is non-empty. Since your argument doesn't use any property of $\mathbb{C}$ other than it is a field, I will change $\mathbb{C}$ to a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For each nontrivial element $g\in G$, the fixed points form a closed set, which must not contain the whole space as then $g$ would act trivially (by reducedness). The complementary open set thus contains the generic point.

The (nonempty, by irreducibility) intersection of these open sets over all nontrivial $g\in G$ forms an open set $U$ which is $G$-invariant. Restricted to $U$, the action of $G$ is free. Thus, the image of $U$ in the stack $[X/G]$ is the quotient $U/G$, which is an algebraic space, and so the image of $U/G$ in the algebraic space $X/G$ is again isomorphic to $U/G$.